Understanding Measurement Accuracy in a Temperature Control System
I’m setting up a small experiment for a personal project. The goal is to control the temperature in a water basin using a PT100 sensor, a PID temperature controller, a Solid State Relay, and an immersion heating element.
For various reasons, I need the temperature measurement system's accuracy—provided via a USB connection from the PID controller—to meet a requirement of ±0.25% of the measured temperature.
Looking at the PT100 datasheet, the accuracy is specified as ±0.03°C at 0°C and ±0.08°C at 100°C. On the other hand, the PID controller datasheet states an accuracy of ±0.4°C or ±0.2% of the reading + 1 digit when using a PT100 sensor.
This raises a few questions:

How should I combine the accuracies of the sensor (PT100) and the
acquisition device (PID controller) to quantify the overall system
accuracy?

Is it common to specify accuracy as "±0.4°C or ±0.2% of the reading + 1 digit"? What does "or" mean in this context? Does it imply choosing the larger of the two values? What does "+ 1 digit" mean in this specification?


I’d greatly appreciate any guidance or insights into this!

What is an SSR?

A solid state Relay

More detail would be helpful.  What process are you trying to temperature control?  What process disturbances are likely?  How large of an excursion from setpoint is acceptable?  What range of temperatures do you intend to measure?  Where is your setpoint in this range?  You will find that process disturbances are (normally) much larger than the precision of your instrumentation, making me wonder why instrumentation precision is such a concern.
